# Calculating pair combinations in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code to calculates and retrieves pair combinations:

```
public static void calculateCombinations(int x){
        int number = combination(x);
        int counter=0,y=0;
        while(counter<number){
            y++;
            for(int i=1; i<=x; i++){
                if(y!=i && !(i<y)){
                    System.out.println(y + " -- " + i);
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public static int combination(int n)
    {
        return permutation(n) / (permutation(2) * permutation(n - 2));
    }

    public static int permutation(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return i * permutation(i - 1);
    }
```

The code works well but it doesn't seem an efficient and professional code. One thing I am worried about here is the running cost of this code because it is part of a very huge project, which I care about the running time. What I want is to re-write it in a very professional way. I found lot of codes that do the same job I want but I only want to write my own code. I am asking you here to suggest how I can improve this function.

Answer (score 1):

## calculateCombinations

Your method does a lot of not required iterating. You only have to iterate up to `x-1` in the outer loop as afterwards the if statement evaluates always to false (-> you can remove the number variable and thus the `#combination` call). The value of `y` and `counter` is the same on each iteration -> you can drop the `counter` variable.
The if statement can be removed by starting the inner loop at `y+1`.
The resulting code would look something like:

```
public static void calculateCombinations(int x) {
    int y = 0;
    while (y < x - 1) {
        y++;
        for (int i = y + 1; i <= x; i++) {
            System.out.println(y + " -- " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be written with two for loops to keep the code shorter:

```
public static void calculateCombinations(int x) {
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
        for (int j = i; ++j <= x;)
            System.out.println(i + " -- " + j);
}
```

Besides that I would rename the method as it prints the combinations, with the current name I would assume that the method returns the combinations.

## permutation

This method is effectively a recursively written loop that returns the product of the range `[1,i]` (=factorial, thus method should be renamed to factorial) and thus can be replaced with:

```
public static int permutation(int i) {
    // should add check for negative values
    int p = 1;
    for (; i > 1; i--)
        p *= i;
    return p;
}
```

For O(1) performance you could precompute the factorials for values up to 12 (all factorials in int range).

Comment: `for (int j = i+1;` etc to maintain behaviour.

Comment: Behavior is the same as `j` is pre incremented in the condition.